# How to randomly select a sample of data according to specified proportions in Python Pandas?

Tags: python, pandas, dataframe, random, sample

I have DataFrame in Python Pandas like below:

| ID | TG |
| --- | --- |
| 111 | 0 |
| 222 | 0 |
| 333 | 1 |
| 444 | 1 |
| 555 | 0 |
| ... | ... |

Above DataFrame has 5 000 000 rows, with:

- 99.40 % -> 0
- 0.60% -> 1

And I need to randomly select sample of this data, so as to have 5% of '1' in column TG.
So as a result I need to have DataFrame with observations where 5% are '1', and rest (95% of '0') randomly selected.

For example I need 200 000 observations from my dataset where 5% will be 1 and rest 0

How can I do that in Python Pandas ?

Answer (score 0):

I'm sure there is some more performant way but maybe this works using [.sample](https://pandas.pydata.org/docs/reference/api/pandas.DataFrame.sample.html)? Based on a dataset of 5_000 rows.

```
zeros = df.query("TG.eq(0)")
frac = int(round(.05 * len(zeros), 0))
ones = df.query("TG.ne(0)").sample(n=frac)

df = pd.concat([ones, zeros]).reset_index(drop=True)
print(df["TG"].value_counts())

0    4719
1     236
```

Comment: Hmmm, do you have other idea? beacause when I used it on my data I have 99.999% of 0 and 0.007% of 1 in dataset, I rather need to have for example 200 000 observations from my dataset where 5% will be 1 and rest 0, do you have some idea ? :)

Comment: See edit based on a fake dataset of 5_000 rows with .6% 1's